# http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":persistence-unit}' is expected error when using restful webservice using netbeans

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, netbeans, jersey, jax-rs

I am deploying a restful webservice using jersey.I am reading this tutorial and doing instructions:
http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm

but I get this error on deploying on server .

> Severe:   Exception while deploying the app [PlayerServer2] :
>   org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 5; columnNumber: 15;
>   Deployment descriptor file META-INF/persistence.xml in archive
>   [classes].  cvc-complex-type.2.4.b: The content of element
>   'persistence' is not complete. One of
>   '{"http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence":persistence-unit}' is
>   expected.

I am using netbean 8.0.1, glassfish server 4.1, JDK 1.8.91, JPA 2.1

Edited:

persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="PlayerServer2PU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/playerdb2</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

Comment: post your `persistence.xml` please

Comment: @Apostolos I edited my post.Thank you.

Comment: can you remove the empty `properties` tag and try again?

Comment: @Apostolos It works. Thank you so much. please add your answer blow so I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove the empty `<properties/>` tag in order for the `persistence.xml` file to be handled correctly.